# Android : Requesting permission (on Marshmallow) for custom content provider from a 3rd party app

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I have created Custom content provider application on Marshmallow. When I try to access the Custom Content Provider's data from a third party app, it gives me a Permission Denial error that asks me to grant the read permission (which I have already provided in android manifest file of 3rd party app). So, I am assuming that the custom content provider permissions fall under dangerous permissions as opposed to what's specified in Android Documentation that says the default permission level is "normal" https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html#plevel

Can anyone give me a good link for accessing custom content provider from a different app.

Comment: "So, I am assuming that the custom content provider permissions fall under dangerous permissions" -- no, it will be whatever your `<permission>` element declares, assuming that you are defining your own custom permission. However, bear in mind that defining custom permissions has security issues prior to Android 5.0, and the app with the `<permission>` needs to be installed before the app with the `<uses-permission>`.

Comment: Thanks. But I haven;t given any permission Level. And Android document says that its normal by default.

Comment: Uninstall both the client app and the provider app. Make sure that your provider app has the `<permission>` and the client has the `<uses-permission>`. Install the provider app, then the client app, in that order. If this now works, your problem was somewhere in there (e.g., client installed before the provider). If the problem persists, you might consider editing your question and posting the full Java stack trace.

Comment: See this https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2012/08/07/granting-content-provider-uri-permissions/

Comment: @CommonsWare : Thanks. I have tried that method previously after reading your comment on some previous post. But its still asking me for read permission. The problem is I am working on Xamarin (cross platform development), although I am only creating Android app. Providing custom permissions is not well defined in the docs as everything is done through attributes. So, that's the reason I was trying to rely on default permission which android says is "normal" by default

Comment: @CommonsWare you are amazing ..Thanks a lot